# Why declare method as static in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

When I define a bean like so :

```
<bean id="testBean2" class="test">
</bean>

<bean id="testBean" factory-bean="testBean2" factory-method="getter"/>

class test {
    public void getter(){};
}
```

I am not required to define the bean as static.

However if I define the bean like so :

```
<bean id="testBean" class="test" factory-method="getter">
 </bean>
```

I receive a Spring error requiring the bean to be static so i need to change it to :

```
   class test {
        public static void getter(){};
    }
```

Why is this occuring ?  Should both implementation not be static?

Comment: It is not the bean that needs to be static but the method. Maybe it is good to rephrase the title of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a static factory (with an associated method) for creating your bean.

With code that looks something like:

```
public class BeanClass {

    private static BeanClass instance = new BeanClass();

    private BeanClass(){
    }        

    public static BeanClass getter(){
       return instance;
    }
}
```

Your spring context can look something like:

```
<bean id="beanClassInstance" class="BeanClass" factory-method="getter"/>
```

This will then use the static factory method instead of trying to instantiate a singleton through the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

In first case, you are telling Spring to use a specific bean (instance of `testBean2`) to provide instance of another bean (`testBean`).

In second case, you are telling that the class of bean `testBean` has a static factory method on its class `test` to provide bean instances.

---

Note that *"factory bean"* is a special term referring to a bean capable of producing other bean. Usually these beans come in the form of [`FactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/FactoryBean.html) implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare the factory method `getter` to be in the very bean `testBean` that you whish to instantiate via the factory-method

*see here:*

```
<bean id="testBean" class="test" factory-method="getter">
```

the only way for that method to be accessible by spring before an instance of the bean exists is to be static.

Otherwise an instance of that bean would have to exist already, turning the factory method into something superfluous.